# DB Error: constraint violation in Civicrm

Tags: php, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, civicrm

SQL query: Copy

```
INSERT INTO `civicrm_activity_contact` 
            (`activity_id` , `contact_id` , `record_type_id` ) 
    VALUES  ( 21102 ,  0 ,  3 );
```

> MySQL said: Documentation
> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cnb_civi`.`civicrm_activity_contact`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_activity_contact_contact_id` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT)**your text**

I am edit my form , and facing this error

Comment: Did you check if `id` with value 0 exists in the `civicrm_contacts`?